# Having more than one Attribute be a Primary Key for an Entity?

Tags: database

Can entities only have one attribute as a primary key? Or perhaps is it possible to have a set of attributes be a primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key is an irreducibly unique *set* of attributes, which means a key can consist of zero, one or more attributes. The requirement that keys are irreducible does not mean they have to be small or consist of a single attribute; it just means that each key must have the smallest number of attributes necessary to fulfill the uniqueness requirement.

A relational table has to have at least one key and it may have many. Any of those keys might consist of several attributes.

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is a logical constraint comprised of a collection of attributes that uniquely identify the members of a set; that collection can have only one member.  In other words, yes.

Natural primary keys are preferred by relational purists, because adding a surrogate key adds additional attributes that are not inherently part of the data model.  Surrogate keys (identity values, for example) are preferred in practice, because they reduce the complexity of join, and boost performance of the indexes that underlie most implementations of relational engines.

See https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3922066/SQL-Server-Natural-Key-Verses-Surrogate-Key.htm for additional discussion.